# jQuery score card form to determine pass or fail

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a simple scorecard form which uses jQuery to automatically calculate the score of submissions depending on field values. Some fields are "critical" which means if they are a fail they automatically fail.

You can see a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/westieuk/WtDMk/288/) to get a better understanding. I have tried to make the code as efficient as possible but would welcome peoples opinions on what improvements can be made.

```
//disable individual radios by#
$("#edit-submitted-calc-verification-completed-idv-correctly-1, #edit-submitted-calc-summary--action-2-notes-1").attr('disabled',true);

$("#webform-component-calc select, #webform-component-calc :radio").change(function(){

   var $score = 0; 
   var $fails = 0;
   var $critFails = 0;


    $('select option:selected, :radio:checked').each(function(){ 

        var $thisVal = $(this).val();
        var $split = $thisVal.split('_');
        var $string = $split[0];
        var $points = parseInt($split[1],10);


      $(this).parents('tr').find('.webform-grid-option').removeClass('pass fail');

      if ($string == 'fail' || $string == 'critical') {

          $(this).parents('.webform-grid-option').addClass('fail');

          if($string == 'fail') {
              $fails += 1;
          }
          if($string == 'critical') {
              $critFails += 1;   
          }
      }

      else {

          $(this).parents('.webform-grid-option').addClass('pass');
           if($string == 'pass' || $string == 'na') {
              $score += $points;  
           }           
        }
    });

    var $finalScore = $score;
    if($critFails > 0){
         var $finalScore = 0;
       }


    var $summary = 'Final Call score: '+$finalScore+'% with '+$fails+' Fails / '+$critFails+' Critical Fails';


    //alert($summary);
    $('#edit-submitted-calc-number-of-fails').val($fails); 
    $('#edit-submitted-calc-call-score').val($score); 
    $('#edit-submitted-calc-critical-failures-number-of-critial-fails').val($critFails); 
    $('#edit-submitted-calc-critical-failures-final-score').val($finalScore); 
    $('#edit-submitted-calc-summary').val($summary); 

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't change anything about the calculation itself. It all quite reasonable the way it is.

There are just two things could be optimized concerning jQuery:

- You should be using `.closet()` instead of `.parents()` since you only need the first (closest) matching parent and not all ancestors.
- Also you can optimize assigning the event handler to the radio buttons by using `.delegate()` (or `.on` with jQUery 1.7) instead.

There are also a few things which personally I'd do differently:

- In the HTML I'd use `th` elements for the question cells and `td` just for the options, allowing you to get rid of the classes `webform-grid-question` and `webform-grid-option`.
- I'm not a big fan of using `$` in variable names, especially if they don't point to a jQuery object.
- I don't like using `input` elements for output. I'd use a "normal" element such as `span` or `div` (or if HTML5 is a option the new `output` element).